# Helper function injected on all python objects?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, metaprogramming, monkeypatching

I'm trying to mimic `methods.grep` from Ruby which simply returns a list of available methods for any object (class or instance) called upon, filtered by regexp pattern passed to `grep`.
Very handy for investigating objects in an interactive prompt.

```
def methods_grep(self, pattern):
    """ returns list of object's method by a regexp pattern """
    from re import search
    return [meth_name for meth_name in dir(self) \
            if search(pattern, meth_name)]
```

Because of Python's limitation not quite clear to me it unfortunately can't be simply inserted in the `object` class ancestor:

```
object.mgrep = classmethod(methods_grep)
# TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'
```

Is there some workaround how to inject all classes or do I have to stick with a global function like `dir` ?

Comment: You can list all the methods an object has using `dir()`, e.g. `dir(some_object)` (edit: ok I see you already know that ;)

Comment: @James I'm aware of that, it's used in the example `methods_grep` function. I need a function available on all objects which returns all available methods *filtered* by the pattern given as argument.

Comment: @James For example `str.mgrep('split')` would return `['_formatter_field_name_split', 'rsplit', 'split', 'splitlines']`.

Comment: You might fake it using the `mock` module, although it might be dicey setting up a `Mock` that delegates every thing to the original `object` type in addition to handling the `mgrep` method as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module called `forbiddenfruit` that enables you to patch built-in objects. It also allows you to reverse the changes. You can find it here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forbiddenfruit/0.1.1

```
from forbiddenfruit import curse    
curse(object, "methods_grep", classmethod(methods_grep))
```

Of course, using this in production code is likely a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting. What's wrong with that module in production use ? Performance issues ?

Comment: Note that this is not a pure Python module. It's a C plugin to Python. This at least makes it less compatible with different Python versions. +1 though since it answers the question.

Comment: @David I was referring to the general practice of modifying built-in types. For your stated purpose it is probably harmless.

Answer (score 2):

There is no workaround AFAIK. I find it quite annoying that you can't alter built-in classes. Personal opinion though.

One way would be to create a base object and force all your objects to inherit from it.

But I don't see the problem to be honest. You can simply use `methods_grep(object, pattern)`, right? You don't have to insert it anywhere.

Comment: This is both safer and less error prone to other people using your library.

Comment: Thanks. I've presumed I'd need to stick with this and leave it as a global function.